# MySQL optimizer won't use my index

Tags: mysql, join, execution-plan, explain

With the following query:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  geoname 
  LEFT JOIN alternatename
    ON geoname.geonameid = alternatename.geonameid
    AND alternatename.isPreferredName = 1 
    AND alternatename.isoLanguage = 'es'
WHERE 
  geoname.fcode = 'ADM2' 
  AND geoname.country = 'ES'
```

I get the following execution plan:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys                           | key                | key_len | ref                              | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | geoname       | ref  | fcode_idx,country_idx,fcode_country_idx | fcode_country_idx  | 42      | const,const                      |   51 | Using index condition |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | alternatename | ref  | IDX_8F82EED4E2097D,idx_geoid_lang_pref  | IDX_8F82EED4E2097D | 4       | acme_geonames.geoname.geonameid  |    1 | Using where           |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------+------+-----------------------+
```

The `IDX_8F82EED4E2097D` is on the `geonameid` field only, while the `idx_geoid_lang_pref` index is on the fields:

1. `geonameid`
2. `isPreferredName`
3. `isoLanguage`

Why doesn't MySQL use the `idx_geoid_lang_pref` index for the `alternatename` join, which I made specifically for this query?

#### Update as asked in comments:

> the exact version of MySQL

5.6.24

> what are the tables sizes?

- geoname: 4.082.489 rows
- alternatename: 2.558.890 rows

> How many rows does the query return?

52

> How much time does it need to run?

`0:00:0.00142580` according to QueryStats

**Note:** my goal is not to speed up this particular request, only to understand why an index which cover the exact fields of the query is not chosen by the optimizer.

> Provide the full SHOW CREATE TABLE statement for each table

```
CREATE TABLE `geoname` (
  `geonameid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `asciiname` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fclass` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fcode` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cc2` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin1` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin2` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin3` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin4` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `population` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `elevation` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gtopo30` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `moddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`geonameid`),
  KEY `fclass_idx` (`fclass`),
  KEY `fcode_idx` (`fcode`),
  KEY `country_idx` (`country`),
  KEY `admin1_idx` (`admin1`),
  KEY `admin2_idx` (`admin2`),
  KEY `fcode_country_idx` (`fcode`,`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10346797 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `alternatename` (
  `alternatenameId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `geonameid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isoLanguage` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `alternateName` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `isPreferredName` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `isShortName` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `isColloquial` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `isHistoric` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`alternatenameId`),
  KEY `IDX_8F82EED4E2097D` (`geonameid`),
  KEY `idx_geoid_lang_pref` (`geonameid`,`isPreferredName`,`isoLanguage`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_8F82EED4E2097D` FOREIGN KEY (`geonameid`) REFERENCES `geoname` (`geonameid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10842837 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: I sure, correct answer for question - WHY? no body excluding few guys from Oracle/Percona/MariaDB who wrote query optimisation can not answer :)
different versions of MySQL have different query optimisation algorythms also.

if You want test it with other index - test it with FORCE index hint

Comment: I would suggest an index with different order: `(isPreferredName, isoLanguage, geonameid)`

Comment: But you haven't provided with the exact version of MySQL (as @a_vlad pointed). And what are the tables sizes? How many rows does the query return? How much time does it need to run?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I updated my question with the data you asked.

Comment: I wonder why there is a question there. The query returns the answer (52 rows) in about a millisecond. Why would anyone care what indexes it uses?

Comment: @ypercube just to understand how things work. Is this kind of questions not welcome here?

Comment: Provide the full `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement for each table; this will show us the engine and the actual index definition.

Comment: @Derek thanks. I added them to the question.

Comment: Although this is a small table, there still may be an optimizer bug.  Suggest you [_write a bug_](http://bugs.mysql.com).

Answer (score 1):

You do not use the `isPreferredName` in your query. This must be a/the reason why the index is not used.

Also, the optimizer decides. It is not because you create an index that it will be used. All depends on the statistics for the table. How many rows? How many different unique values? What is the expected percentage of returned rows?

Comment: Sorry, I do use the `isPreferredName` field in my query, my bad, I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL already **can filter down to 1 row** by using a different smaller index (only 4 bytes).

```
|  1 | SIMPLE      | alternatename | ref  | IDX_8F82EED4E2097D,idx_geoid_lang_pref  | IDX_8F82EED4E2097D | 4       | acme_geonames.geoname.geonameid  |    1 | Using where
```

So it doesn't need to use the bigger index.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I don't think this point helps any -- (1) drill down secondary BTree via geonameid, (2) drill down primary BTree to find the other 2 fields and check them.  With the bigger index, "(2)" is avoided for the cases where they fail.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange KEY `idx_geoid_lang_pref` (`geonameid`,`isPreferredName`,`isoLanguage`), to put `geonameid` at the end.

In `SELECT *`, how many of the fields of `alternatename` do you need?  If only one, do a subquery instead of a `JOIN`.

I see no good reason to have `alternatenameId`.  And `alternatename`.`geonameid` is unique, correct?  Hence, `geonameid` could be the `PRIMARY KEY` for that table.

Comment: My goal is not to correct the query to make it more efficient. What I want is understand the decision of the optimizer. And alternatename.geonameid is not unique, nope, as one geoname can have multiple alternatenames. It is a very badly designed schema but this is another topic.

Comment: Well, I don't understand why it picked the shorter index.  It seems like a 'bug' in the optimizer.  bugs.mysql.com might get to the optimizer guys and get the real answer.  They are currently keen on "getting it right" in 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

It gains little by using your index, and it takes more memory to load that index due to the additional columns.

Since you `SELECT *` it still needs all the columns in the `alternatename` table, so the fact that it can locate the rows faster with your `idx_geoid_lang_pref` has to be offset by the fact that it still needs to make an extra trip to the clustered index anyway.

So, it is likely choosing the shorter index in order to load more of it into memory at once, find rows that match that one column, then go back to the clustered index to filter out the remaining records, since it needs to go to the clustered anyway in order to fulfill your `SELECT *` clause.

I'm not an expert in optimizer design or functionality by any means, but this is a logical reason that it has to make this decision. Whether it is right to do so is not something I know.

If you really want to get the most benefit out of indexes, make sure they are covering indexes. That means all the columns in both the `WHERE` and the `SELECT` clause need to be in the index, not just the `WHERE` clause.